# Where do I start debugging font issues in epub3?

Tags: css, fonts, resize, font-size, epub3

I am converting a book to ePub3 format.  It is mathematical and my conversion system produces MathML for the mathematics.  One of the platforms I'd like to get working with this is iBooks.  However, figuring out what's going on is ... difficult!  How to correct it is similar.

The first experiment had lots of missing glyphs so I embedded a few of the STIX font files to cover them and that seemed to fix it (for the main, there appear to be a few left that I've not tracked down).  The problem that I am running into now is some rather strange behaviour when I resize the text.  At certain sizes, certain fonts go haywire.

Ideally, I'd love it if someone could tell me how to correctly embed the fonts so that this doesn't happen!  Failing that, I'd settle for a reference to some resource that I could study to figure out what's going on and how to fix it.

The book itself can be [downloaded](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/documents/HoTT-main.epub).  The relevant parts of the CSS are (I think):

```
@font-face {font-family: 'STIXGeneral'; font-weight: regular; font-style: normal; src: url(STIXGeneral.otf) format('opentype'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'STIXGeneral'; font-weight: regular; font-style: italic; src: url(STIXGeneralItalic.otf) format('opentype'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'STIXGeneral'; font-weight: regular; font-style: normal; src: url(STIXGeneralBol.otf) format('opentype'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'STIXGeneral'; font-weight: regular; font-style: italic; src: url(STIXGeneralBolIta.otf) format('opentype'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'STIXIntegral'; font-weight: regular; font-style: normal; src: url(STIXIntDReg.otf) format('opentype'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'STIXIntegral'; font-weight: regular; font-style: normal; src: url(STIXIntDBol.otf) format('opentype'); }
math {font-family: serif, STIXGeneral, STIXIntegral;}
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like when the size is chosen *just right*:

[image: bizarre fonts in an epub]

Comment: The link you give is broken - there's nothing like that under http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/code/

Answer (score 1):

iBooks MathML support is incomplete, unfortunately. In particular it's [been reported](http://www.baldurbjarnason.com/notes/ibooks-30/) that it's subject to running out of memory while rendering complex math and giving up. You may not have a viable workaround at this time. Does the issue occur with just a subset of the content?

Comment: I had a suspicion this might be a factor, though I'm surprised by the consistency of the problem.  Might it help if I split the book into smaller component files?  At the moment I regard MathML in iBooks as Dr Johnson's dog: amazing that it does it at all.  Incidentally, your tutorials on the IBM site were invaluable for figuring out what an epub3 looks like.  Many thanks for those!

Comment: Yeah, try a single OPF file with just that problematic bit and see if it occurs. (And you're welcome, glad they were helpful!)

Comment: It seems much better if I explicitly specify a main font for the whole book.  Previously I was just specifying a specific font for the mathematics and leaving the main font blank.  I think that then it was trying to use the maths font (STIX) for the main text.  Explicitly specifying, say, Palatino seems to have fixed it.  But this is all trial-and-error stuff; it'd be great if there were something like Firebug for iBooks where I could tweak settings and add css rules on a live book.

Comment: Indeed. Hopefully something like that will be included with the OS X desktop version of iBooks when it comes out this fall.